# How to filter one column using other in obiee?

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle12c, obiee

I use OracleBI 12c. We had to create a analysis. Let's say we need to show all the clients with account  code starting with '202%' and at  the same time we should check if that client also has account_code starting with '226%' . If they have then show them, else don't.

It may sound simple, but all filter options I tried didn't give the wanted output. Also I tried to use selection steps but didn't succeed either.I could have done that using FILTER in Column formula, but since the column is not a measure attribute it throws error 'Filter funciton requires at least one measure attribute in its first argument'.

Have somebody had this kind of issue?

Comment: Why did selection steps not give you the desired results? Because this is exactly what they are there for. What did you do? Precisely?

Comment: First, I used condition remove clients where account_code doesn't begin with 226%, but it removes also clients whose account_code begins with 202%. What I want is check if there is an account starting with 226% and if it exists, then show that client's account that begins with 202%

Comment: So the firs step would be "Keep only 226%" and then "Add "202%". Not sure why this should be an issue

Comment: yes, but when adding 202% does query make sure that this 202% corresponds to client who has account beginning 226%, or it just adds all clients who have accounts beginning 226% not considering existance of 226%? When I checked It didnt.